# EJB method being called multiple times

Tags: jpa, ejb, payara

I am developing a JEE8 Application on Payara 5 Server. I have a method in one of my stateless EJBs that I invoke only once (from JSF page) but on the server side it gets called executed multiple times. I have tried the method on Payara5.192, Payara 5.193 and Glassfish 5 as well. But I keep getting the same issue. Code below-

```
@Override
    public List<Forum> getForums(int startIndex, int size) {
        TypedQuery<Forum> tQ=em.createQuery("select f from Forum f", Forum.class);
        tQ.setFirstResult(startIndex);
        tQ.setMaxResults(size);
        List<Forum> toReturn=tQ.getResultList();
        LOGGER.info("Forums extracted "+toReturn.size());
        return toReturn;
    }
```

If I start the pagination from the index 0 and with the result size of 5, the LOGGER.info generates the following log, which looks absurd!

```
Info:   Forums extracted 5
Info:   Forums extracted 5
Info:   Forums extracted 5
Info:   Forums extracted 5
Info:   Forums extracted 5
Info:   Forums extracted 5
```

Moreover, the number of times this loops go is not fixed either. It can get executed between 15-30 times. whereas I expect only one log message, obviously.

Comment: Log also incoming parameters, startIndex & size. Is it exactly the same call?

Comment: @pirho, yes they are the same parameters indeed. In fact, I did mention this in the problem statement -"If I start the pagination from the index 0 and with the result size of 5". Thanks for looking into this though.

Comment: Yes I noticed that but actually what I wanted to know was that if the one and only call 0/5 would somehow have generated calls to  - say - 5/5 and 10/5 and so on... But apparently it is not so.

Comment: Can you please provide more context information like the JSF view, the backing bean, and your stateless EJB?

Answer (score 0):

If you use #{managedBean.forums} as a value of a JSF component your method may be called multiple times, because any time the component needs to access the data it will call the getter.

The way to do this in JSF is implement a method that loads the data and call it from the @PostConstruct method, and every time you need to reload the data. The method used in the value property of the JSF component shoud be a simple getter that only returns the data:

```
private List<Forum> forums;

public List<Forum> getForums() {
    return forums;
}

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    loadForums();
}

public void loadForums() {
    TypedQuery<Forum> tQ=em.createQuery("select f from Forum f", Forum.class);
    tQ.setFirstResult(startIndex);
    tQ.setMaxResults(size);
    forums =tQ.getResultList();
    LOGGER.info("Forums extracted "+forums.size());
}
```